# Let G be a finite subgroup of $GL_n(k) $ where K is an algeraically closed field. Then...

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

> Let G be a finite subgroup of $GL_n(k) $ where k is an algeraically closed field. Then Choose the correct statements from below:

(a) Every elements of G is diagonalizable

(b) Every elements of G is diagonalizable if k is an algebraic closure of $\mathbb{Q}$

(c) Every elements of G is diagonalizable if k is algebraic closure of $\mathbb{F}_p$

(d) There exists a basis of $k^n$ wrt to which every element of G is a diagonal matrix.

I have proved that (A) and (D) holds but I am unable to understand why (B) and (C) must be false.  I think (B) and (C) must be true because (A) holds and there is no condition in (A)?

> But where I am making mistake?

Comment: If (d) holds then $G$ is abelian. Because diagonal matrices commute with each other.

Answer (score 2):

Let $k=\overline{\Bbb F_p}$ and consider the finite subgroup $G$ of $\mathrm{GL}_2(k)$ given by $\{\begin{pmatrix} 1 & x\\ 0 & 1\end{pmatrix},x \in \Bbb F_p\}$. Then except for the identity, no element of $G$ is diagonalizable, showing that (a),(c) and (d) are wrong.

(b) is true: if $g \in G$, then the subgroup generated by $g$ is cyclic, hence abelian. A representation of an abelian finite group over an algebraically closed field of characteristic $0$ is diagonalizable.
Or if you want a more elementary proof: If $g \in G$, then $g$ is a finite order matrix which means that $g^n-I=0$ for some $n$. This implies that the minimal polynomial of $g$ divides $x^m-1$. But $x^m-1$ splits over $\overline{\Bbb Q}$ as a product of distinct linear factors, hence so does the minimal polynomial of $g$. Thus $g$ is diagonalizable by linear algebra.

Comment: Yes, thank you(+1).